# 500 Server Error in my Django App in App Engine (Google Cloud)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, server

I am new to Google Cloud an I followed the steps in https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine and deployed the App successfully. However, when I go to the page `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com` the next message is displayed:

> Error: Server Error
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

I have seen this is something really usual but cannot find any useful solution. I would appreciate any help.

---

my settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = '…'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'KhalilApp.apps.KhalilappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoServer.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'KhalilApp/templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Mapilib')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoServer.wsgi.application'

import pymysql  # noqa: 402
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)  # change mysqlclient version
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/…’,
            'USER': 'maestros',
            'PASSWORD': '…',
            'NAME': 'principal',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '…',
            'NAME': 'principal',
            'USER': 'maestros',
            'PASSWORD': '…',
        }
    }
if os.getenv('TRAMPOLINE_CI', None):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
        }
    }

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

Comment: Your question has no details such as the HTTP request that is failing, the application code, the application errors (PHP log files), etc. You will only get tips and guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your code. 500 Server Error means you have something wrong in your application.

Comment: Hello Atom, thanks for you reply. The application is working fine in my local host, what kind of errors in the code could cause that?

Comment: The deployment settings in the production and local host are different. Please find according to your application. Set DEBUG=TRUE in production for few moments, you will find the errors

Comment: I deployed 2 versions, one with DEBUG=TRUE and another one with DEBUG=FALSE and neither of them worked. However, in the registry I can find an error referring to /favicon.ico. I do not know what that means.

Comment: did you set up nginx and gunicorn properly? Follow the proper documentation don't miss the steps , the error related to /favicon.ico means that the file is not found which is not a reason for the 500 server error.

Comment: I think that may be the problem, since before getting the 500 error it returned an error 502 bad gateway nginx. But I modified the app.yaml and it changed. I will try and follow the proper steps.

Comment: Hi Atom, I am having troubles to find the documentation to set up nginx and gunicorn. Any idea where I can find it?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to configure gunicorn in App Engine Standard, please add the following line into your app.yaml file:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

You can check the following [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup) to add an entrypoint to start gunicorn that listens on the port specified by the PORT environment variable

Comment: Please delete the previous comment as it contains your Project ID. It is considered as PII Data please remove it as soon possible. You have attached a filter in the comment, please share logs of the complete error.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please have a look to it.

Comment: Does this give you a hint?                                                                                   startTime: "2021-03-10T07:50:26.510609Z"
endTime: "2021-03-10T07:50:26.511737Z"
latency: "0.001128s"
method: "GET"
resource: "/favicon.ico"
httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"
status: 500

Comment: line: [
0: {
time: "2021-03-10T07:50:26.511699Z"
severity: "ERROR"
logMessage: "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully"
}
]
appEngineRelease: "1.9.71"

Comment: httpRequest: {
status: 500
}
resource: {
type: "gae_app"

Comment: The 500 means that you have an error in  your code, there should be more logs in Stackdriver, please check them or share minimal reproducible code snippet as I followed the Official Documentation you shared, and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: I will share the settings.py in the question. When DEBUG=True the error displayed is 500 and when DEBUG=False it is an error 502. So it makes me think the errors have something to do with my settings.py

Comment: With settings.py, we can't determine why are you getting those errors.  500 errors are coming from your application. Have you check [Django first app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) ? Please share your app.yaml file.