# Google App Engine Django Project Infinite Loading and error 500 does not raise any error in logs

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

Im am trying to deploy a Django project on Google Cloud App Engine.

I deployed my app using the command `gcloud app deploy`.

**As I try to load the page in my browser, there is an infinite loading until the page finally returns a "Server 500 Error".**

I decited then to see if there is something weird in the logs by executing `gcloud app logs tail` but it does not raise any type of error, this is what i get.

```
2021-11-26 17:38:31 default[version_code]  [2021-11-26 17:38:31 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-11-26 17:38:31 default[version_code]  [2021-11-26 17:38:31 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (11)
2021-11-26 17:38:31 default[version_code]  [2021-11-26 17:38:31 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-11-26 17:38:31 default[version_code]  [2021-11-26 17:38:31 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
```

**ALSO IN ERROR REPORTING PAGE OF GOOGLE CLOUD NOTHING APPEARS**

This is my Python Django `settings.py`:

```py
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'HOST': 'cloudsql/<my-google-cloudsql-connection-string>',
            'NAME': 'database_name',
            'USER': 'username',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
```

This is my `app.yaml` file:

```yaml
runtime: python39
env: standard
app_engine_apis: true
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /.*
  script: auto

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8000 NG.wsgi
```

I also get this warning during the deploy: `Updating service [default]...|WARNING: There is a dependency on App Engine APIs, but they are not enabled in your app.yaml. Set the app_engine_apis property.`.

In my *app.yaml* I configured the *app_engine_apis* property, so, why is it raising the Warning?

### **EDIT 1:**

I just checked if the problem is generated by the database connection, but actually, it's not. If there isn't any error, the page doesn't even load, what I think is that I messed up some configuration, but, I just followed the steps on the official WebSite of GoogleCloud

Comment: Can you confirm the value of the env variable, ```GAE_APPLICATION```? Also curious as to why your entry point is the port on which your cloud SQL is running

Comment: The fact is that if I try to do `print(os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None))` it does not print anything.. it's like the program does not even start... By the way I'll try to change the port

Comment: I changed the port from 5432 to 8000 of entrypoint value in `app.yaml` but nothing changes. I still get that four lines from the logs

Comment: don't think your work around will work because ```BASE DIR``` would indicate a local path and standard env only has access to ```/tmp``` which is basically in memory. Does your app work on your local machine?

Comment: my app just works on local machine. I tried for days trying to fix this. I have to commit this work in 30 days from now and I have no idea of how to solve this problem. The page just loads infinitely until, after 5 or 10 minutes of loading, it raises a 500 error. In my code there are no errors: for example, if I make a syntax error on purpose, it appears in the logs, but, as I said, i have no errors in my code and I can't still see my website running properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by just removing this line on `app.yaml` file.

That's the line `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8000 NG.wsgi`

I guess you do not have to specify the entrypoint when deploying a Django application on App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for similar issues with the "500 server error" I found something that can be useful for you.

Apparently this error is received due to application errors as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66545380/16938011), the user also talks about taking a look at the deployment settings since the production and local hosts are different and set `DEBUG = FALSE`.  Here is a guide on how to [configure your app for production](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#configuring_for_production).

Another [question](https://serverfault.com/a/896597/942113) points to look for the [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/quickstart) panel in Google Cloud Platform dashboard to get a stacktrace to the problem in your code, if it is there. This can be helpful to solve a 500 error.

In the same question a user answers this issue is hard to solve straightforwardly and that you need to investigate for various reasons as we can see in this [discussion](https://github.com/nytimes/library/issues/38#issuecomment-500873942), where they asked the OP for their logs to provide further help. Then, after checking them the OP got his own solution.

I would suggest looking at the configuration to check everything is ok for production deployment, try to check for more information in the Error Reporting panel and if you have the logs and you are still not able to troubleshoot the issue posting another or updating the question with this information.

Comment: I tried for days for everything mate. If there are no errors in the code, the page does an infinite loading. I have to commit this website in 30 days, i just need to do this step. Literally tried for everything. The logs says nothing, the page says nothing. It just works on localhost. I am desperate. Example of what log says: `2021-11-26 15:46:35.517 UTC [1755516]: [2-1] db=,user= LOG:  automatic analyze of table "cloudsqladmin.public.heartbeat" system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s`. No errors mentioned

Comment: Following the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) and the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart), I was able to deploy the app, but comparing the docs you have provided with these and the [Github example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/5ceff2520ecced7e1284f5ce0592b93dafcf3817/appengine/standard_python3/django/mysite/settings.py), several differences were found. I would recommend you to use the Secrets Manager with environ. Please check this question 62311579 that explains the structure.

Comment: i did like that in the past, but it doesn't work. Now I've tried another time, and it doesn't work. That's the error I get if I follow the steps: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "/cloudsql/projectid:europe-west3:name" to address: Unknown host`. So i decited to manually add the database variable dict like in the question. If i do like this it work, but the page doesn't load. And that's my database URL: `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pass@//cloudsql/project_id:europe-west3:project_name/db_name`. I am wondering, why isn't the port specified?